# "You got to be kidding me!" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

What is the correct translation/specific word for *kidding* in German in this context?

Comment: "Das ist doch nicht dein Ernst?" – http://de.pons.com/übersetzung?q=kidding&l=deen&in=&lf=de

Comment: Echt jetzt? Das ist Deine Frage?

Answer (score 6):

My proposal avoids harsh words:

> Du nimmst mich wohl auf den Arm?!

Answer (score 3):

“You got to be kidding me!”: “Du machst wohl Scherze!”, or vulgar: “Du willst mich wohl verarschen!”
You can translate “kidding” with “Scherz”.

Comment: 'Verarschen' is more of getting pissed off at, right? Scherze is a new word for me.

Comment: Yes, it is. But in everyday language (friends, family) we often use it without getting pissed off. “Scherz” is something said or done for amusement, not in seriousness.

Comment: doesn't really work. "you've got to be kidding me" is often used without directly addressing another person to express annoyance or disbelieve at a situation. you wouldn't use "du willst mich wohl verarschen" in that situations.

Answer (score 2):

*Das kann doch nicht wahr sein!*
(That can't possibly be true!) communicates a level of astonishment that is included in "You've got to be kidding me!"

*Verarschen* has an implication of making fun of the person.  (Making them look like an ass.)

If you look on [Leo](http://dict.leo.org/#/search=kidding&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on) you will also find "veralbern".